# How do I combine multiple queries?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to combine two result sets and I feel I am so close but just don't see how to wrap this all up:

Here's one query with a small result set, (give me inactives)

```
SELECT MAX(set_date) AS most_recent_inactive, key_value, statusid
FROM status_history
WHERE base_table = 'userinfo'  
AND statusid = 10 AND set_date > TO_DATE('2012-10-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY key_value, statusid
```

**Output:**

```
recent_inactive key_value statusid
2013-01-30  15  10
2013-06-04  261 10
2013-06-18  352 10
2012-10-04  383 10
2013-01-22  488 10
2013-03-04  711 10
2013-06-19  749 10
2013-03-05  806 10
```

Another query with a small result set (give me actives)

```
SELECT MAX (set_date) AS most_recent_active, key_value, statusid
FROM status_history
WHERE base_table = 'userinfo'  
AND statusid =11
GROUP BY key_value, statusid
```

**Output:**

```
recent_active key_value statusid
2002-01-01  3   11
2002-01-01  5   11
2002-01-01  14  11
2002-01-01  15  11
2002-01-01  21  11
2002-01-01  23  11
2002-01-01  25  11
2002-01-01  26  11
```

I want to get all of the actives and inactives together, so I union them all

```
SELECT NULL AS most_recent_active, MAX(set_date) AS most_recent_inactive, key_value, statusid
FROM status_history
WHERE base_table = 'userinfo'  
AND statusid = 10 AND set_date > TO_DATE('2012-10-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY key_value, statusid
    UNION all
SELECT MAX(set_date) AS most_recent_active, NULL AS most_recent_inactive, key_value, statusid
FROM status_history
WHERE base_table = 'userinfo'  
AND statusid = 11
GROUP BY key_value, statusid
ORDER by key_value
```

**Output:**

```
recent_active recent_inactive key_value statusid
2002-01-01  null    3   11
2002-01-01  null    5   11
2002-01-01  null    14  11
null  2013-01-30    15  10
2002-01-01  null    15  11
2002-01-01  null    21  11
2002-01-01  null    23  11
2002-01-01  null    25  11
2002-01-01  null    26  11
2002-01-01  null    27  11
2002-01-01  null    29  1
```

The problem is key_value 15 is duplicated.

The values are correct, but i want that record and all subsequent duplicates "flattened," row 15 and all other matches coming through as one record with both date fields set.

Again, I feel I'm so close but how do I wrap this all up?

Thank you?

Comment: Which status id are you going to want when you flatten row 15?

Comment: I need statusid of 10. But, if recent_inactive has a value, statusid will always be 10 because that's by definition, I have an inactive date because they're inactive, statusid 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is assuming that your inactive status_id is always less than your active status_id. This may not work if there are other possible status_id values.

```
select max(most_recent_active), max(most_recent_inactive), key_value, min(status_id)
from (select null as most_recent_active, max(set_date) as most_recent_inactive, key_value,statusid
from status_history
where base_table = 'userinfo'  
and statusid = 10 and set_date > to_date('2012-10-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
group by key_value,statusid
    UNION all
select max(set_date) as most_recent_active, null as most_recent_inactive, key_value,statusid
from status_history
where base_table = 'userinfo'  
and statusid = 11
group by key_value,statusid
order by key_value)
group by key_value
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a CASE statement to split out which are inactive and which are active. The default, if the case is not fulfilled is NULL so you'll get what you want.

```
select max(case when statusid = 10 then set_date end) as most_recent_inactive
     , max(case when statusid = 11 then set_date end) as most_recent_active
     , key_value
     , max(statusid) as statusid
  from status_history
 where base_table = 'userinfo'  
   and statusid in (10, 11)
 group by key_value, statusid
```

The date thing you've got going on in the inactive is a little strange but if you want to restrict just put this in the CASE for inactive dates:

```
select max(case when statusid = 10  
                      and set_date > to_date('2012-10-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                     then set_date 
           end) as most_recent_inactive
     , max(case when statusid = 11 then set_date end) as most_recent_active
     , key_value
     , max(statusid) as statusid
  from status_history
 where base_table = 'userinfo'  
   and statusid in (10, 11)
 group by key_value, statusid
```

I've assumed that if something is both active and inactive you want to display that it's active. If you want to display it as inactive use `min(statusid)`; if you want to display both then you need another column... follow the same logic; use a CASE statement. If you want neither then remove it from the SELECT and GROUP BY clauses completely.

Comment: The first query isn't good because I'm getting multiple results for key_value. Second query, missing expression.

Comment: If something's inactive _and_ active do you want it to be inactive or active @dazed-and-confused? The second is really simple; I have two `and`s, you could just remove one... but it would come up with the same result.

Comment: The statusid doesn't matter. The inactive_date tells me I'm inactive. I just need the dates.

Comment: I've altered my answer; if the statusid doesn't matter then just remove it. That's what's causing your problems.

Comment: This gives me the correct result I want. The other answer does as well but this is cleaner as it doesn't have my ugly union. Now I hope I can properly join this result set with the larger outer set (not mentioned here). Thanks

Comment: Changing the answer because the union all answer ultimately yields the result I need. Thanks again.

Comment: The union isn't just ugly @dazed-and-confused; it's also less efficient as you're going to scan the table twice... you should easily be able to join it onto a larger result-set.

Answer (score 0):

Do `GROUP BY` **after** the union.

```
SELECT MAX(active) As most_recent_active,  MAX(inactive) As most_recent_in_active,
       key_value, statusid
FROM
(SELECT null as active, set_date as inactive, key_value, statusid
 FROM status_history
 WHERE base_table = 'userinfo'  
       AND statusid = 10 and set_date > to_date('2012-10-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')

    UNION ALL

 SELECT set_date as active, null as inactive, key_value, statusid
 FROM status_history
 WHERE base_table = 'userinfo'  
       AND statusid = 11)

 GROUP BY key_value, statusid
 ORDER BY by key_value
```